# Every normal modal logic Σ contains ¬♢⊥.

Tags: logic, modal-logic

The following proposition comes from this PDF: http://builds.openlogicproject.org/content/normal-modal-logic/normal-modal-logic.pdf (p.31)

It says: *Every normal modal logic Σ contains ¬♢⊥.*

The problem beneath it says to prove this. I don't really know how I would e able to prove this. Can someone help me?

The **definition of a normal modal** logic can be found under definition 3.5 it says:

A modal logic Σ is normal if it contains

□(p → q) → (□p → □q), (K)

♢p ↔ ¬□¬p (dual)

and is closed under necessitation, i.e., if φ ∈ Σ, then □φ ∈ Σ.
Observe that while tautological implication is “fine-grained” enough to preserve truth at a world, the rule nec only preserves truth in a model (and hence
also validity in a frame or in a class of frames).

Thank you!

Comment: presumably $\sum$ also contains all tautologies; no doubt what you do here is start with an appropriate tautology and apply a few rules...

Comment: Which tautology could I start with? I really don't have a clue right now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clue: you want to rewrite what you want to prove with a box. How?

Clue: what is the logical status of $\neg\bot$?

If the answer to the second doesn’t hit you immediately then perhaps it is propositional logic you first need to get clearer about!

Comment: ⊥ is the propositional constant for falsity. So if we have the negation of it (¬⊥) then we can also write the propositional constant for truth, which is "⊤". Right? And when I rewrite what I want with a box I may write □⊤ instead maybe?

Comment: $\neg\bot$ is a tautology. So by the necessitation rule, $\Box\neg\bot$ ...

Comment: So I instead can prove that every normal modal logic Σ contains □¬⊥?

Comment: ♢p ↔ ¬□¬p so ......

Comment: Oh, I understand it now I think. I can use the dual for my prove. So if ♢p ↔ ¬□¬p, then we can also say that ¬♢⊥↔□¬⊥?

Comment: Nevermind I understood it now! Thanks for helping me, the clues helped me out!

Comment: @Kylie If this answer resolved your question, you can "accept" it by clicking the green check mark on the left. Welcome to Math Stackexchange!

Answer (score 0):

This answer contains a hint and my guess as to the authors' intent behind the problem. This answer intentionally does not contain a complete proof/argument.

---

On page 31, as part of definition 3.5, the authors of Boxes and Diamonds observe that a modal logic satisfying axiom $K$, the duality of $\lozenge$ and $\square$, and the rule of necessitation is normal and the relational semantics first described in section 1.4 are adequate for producing a sound and complete semantics of such a modal logic. The text immediately below the definition that you cited suggests to me that the authors intend readers to use a semantic proof for this problem.

We can use this result and argue using the relational semantics.

I claim $W, R, w \Vdash \lnot \lozenge \bot$ is always true.

We can prove this by looking at the truth conditions of $\lnot$, $\lozenge$, and $\bot$.

As an example, here are the truth conditions of $\lor$ and $\square$.

$W, R, w \Vdash \varphi \lor \psi$ holds if and only if $W, R, w \Vdash \varphi$ holds or $W, R, w \Vdash \psi$ holds. This makes sense: intuitively, we can assess the truth of an expression headed by $\lor$ without travelling to other worlds besides $w$.

$W, R, w \Vdash \square \varphi$ holds if and only if $W, R, u \Vdash \varphi$ holds at every possible world $u$ that's $R$-accessible from $w$. This holds vacuously if there are no accessible worlds. Assessing the truth of a statement headed by $\square$ forces us to look at worlds adjacent to $w$, which also makes intuitive sense.

Comment: How exactly would this be proven? I do not know much about the truth conditions, since I only read the first 3 chapters.

Comment: It would be a semantic argument, similar to how problems are intended to be solved in earlier sections of Boxes and Diamonds. For example, $W, R, w \Vdash \varphi \lor \psi$ holds if and only if $W, R, w \Vdash \varphi$ holds and $W, R, w \Vdash \psi$ holds. You can always take an expression like $\lnot \lozenge \bot$, see what the outermost connective is, and define when it's true using natural language and "ordinary mathematical reasoning" as glue and other instances of $W, R, w \Vdash \cdots$ ... the trick is that the other instances of $W, R, w \Vdash \cdots$ will involve shorter wffs.

Comment: By a "semantic argument", I just mean "an argument appealing to the semantics of modal logic" rather than proving something directly in a fixed proof calculus. By the truth conditions, I just mean the sentences like "$W, R, w \Vdash \cdots $ if and only if ..." that describe the meaning of wffs in modal logic by describing when they're true (given a set of worlds, accessibility relation, and distinguished world).